# Common practice for handling time field EditTexts?

Tags: android, time, android-edittext

So if I have three EditTexts: one for hours, minutes, seconds, with a max length of two numbers per field, it is conceivable that someone inputs "99" seconds or "99" hours for example -- numbers that are >=60.

If someone entered 60 seconds you'd want this to be the same as "1 minute 00 seconds" for example.

Is there a common practice for this, or a common input field in Android that allows for the input of time in a standardized way?

Because otherwise I end up delving into this awkward dance of trying to "translate" the EditTexts when someone is done editing them (apparently there's no clean, consistent way to do this), but then there is the issue of what happens when someone enters all 9's and there is no room to "carry over" anything.

Is there a standardized input for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a standard widget to enter a time in Android. You can see it in different forms here and there. It's [TimePicker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html) widget. You can find a quick tutorial [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html).

Comment: I am not asking about this